# Change DatePickers "Select a date" to the DisplayDate on load like "02-03-2003"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I cant find anyway to change the "startup" text of the Datepicker and I want it to display the DisplayDate I have entered instead of "Select a Date"

Another thing, is it possible to remove the possibility to type in dates?

I am thinking of trying http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/09/11/wpf-datepicker/ as until now I am not mighty impressed with the default one (Or I am using it wrong)

Comment: I completely rewrote the WinForms DateTimePicker because of its gross inadequacy. It's both unsurprising and disappointing that the WPF one might be similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `SelectedDate` property

Comment: Well LogDatePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now; it gives a  TargetEvocation exception

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xajyiS36 gives {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}

Comment: I pasted this code in a sample app and it works fine.  Where is that code being called from?  Two lines of code does not give much context as to how it is being used.  Have you set a break point and confirmed it is that line and not something else?

Comment: It was my SelectionChanged event that screwed it over :x

Comment: `SelectedDate` needs to be a DateTime.

Comment: @Cosmin I don't understand what you are trying to say.  Nowhere in the question or answer does anyone suggest that `SelectedDate` is not a `DateTime`.  In fact, the first comment here sets it to `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: @cadrell0 Indeed, I did not read the full question text, I only read ”I cant find anyway to change the "startup" text of the Datepicker”; sorry